# Compilation error - Makefile logs

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I'm executing command `make -dwp all` to compile a C++ S/W.
On the logs I'm facing the following error message:

EDIT: Preceding lines

```
         Finished prerequisites of target file `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
         Prerequisite `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.hex1' is newer than target `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
         Prerequisite `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.hex2' is newer than target `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
         Prerequisite `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/program.def' is newer than target `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
         Prerequisite `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.abs.map' is newer than target `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
         Prerequisite `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/dbgsym.blk' is newer than target `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
        Must remake target `/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc'.
Creating DLPRAER.rpc
Got a SIGCHLD; 2 unreaped children.
Putting child 0x00094800 (/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc) PID 4672 on the chain.
Live child 0x00094800 (/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc) PID 4672 
Reaping winning child 0x00094800 PID 4672 
/export/home/bcmsa/nba//tools/RPG3_toolbox_r4a/bin/obsrec -v -p -K -c 0x10000034 -d 0x40000000 -b 0xa0000000 -q -u30 -y20 -V program.def DLPRAER.hex1 DLPRAER.hex2 DLPRAER DLPRAER
Live child 0x00094800 (/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc) PID 4673 
rpgformx -p -c 0x10000034 -d 0x40000000 -b 0xa0000000 -o DLPRAER.chk DLPRAER.hex1 DLPRAER.hex2 program.def 

Error: Size of sections changed between files
ERROR : Couldn't run rpgform
Got a SIGCHLD; 1 unreaped children.
Reaping losing child 0x00094800 PID 4673 
make: *** [/export/home/bcmsa/nba/DLPRTER_CAA/bin/RPG3/default/DLPRAER.rpc] Error 1
Removing child 0x00094800 PID 4673  from chain.
```

I'm sorry for the question, but I'm still learning to debug makefile.
Can anyone give a clue of the problem?

If more information is needed, please comment it, then I'll edit the question.

Comment: Check DLPRAER.rpc. It is a rpc, see if any other process is also using its dependables ? Put in come echo statements inside your Makefile. Not a great idea but may throw some light.

Comment: How can I check if any other process is using its dependables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed the command `make clean` and then I tried again `make -dwp` and no errors messages so far.

The problem was DLPRAER.rpc

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a problem with the makefile, it looks like a problem with one of the tools the makefile runs.   Do you know what rpgform is (supposed to be) doing?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what rpgform supposed to be doing, but I'm looking for more information about it. As soon as I got more information I'll post it.